Troubleshooting NextAuth Google Sign-In with Sanity in Next.js 15 – Callback Issues and User Profile Creation
I’m working on a project with Next.js 15 and TypeScript, and I’m having trouble setting up authentication using NextAuth and Google Sign-In. I’m trying to fetch and create user data in Sanity based on Google profile info, but I’m running into some issues.
Here’s my auth.ts file:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { client } from "./sanity/lib/client";
import { AUTHOR_BY_GOOGLE_ID } from "./sanity/lib/queries";
import { writeClient } from "./sanity/lib/write-client";

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  providers: [Google],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user: { name, email, image }, profile: { id, login, bio } }) {
      const existingUser = await client
        .withConfig({ useCdn: false })
        .fetch(AUTHOR_BY_GOOGLE_ID, { id });

      if (!existingUser) {
        await writeClient.create({
          _type: "author",
          id,
          name,
          username: login,
          email,
          image,
          bio: bio || "",
        });
      }
      return true;
    },
    async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      if (account && profile) {
        const user = await client
          .withConfig({ useCdn: false })
          .fetch(AUTHOR_BY_GOOGLE_ID, { id: profile?.id });
        token.id = user?._id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      Object.assign(session, { id: token.id });
      return session;
    },
  }
});

When I remove the signIn callback (shown below), everything works fine, and Google authentication completes without issues
